# AS3 - Setting BitmapData Dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata

I'm brand new to AS3, trying to take a bitmap from the library and display it in the timeline with actionscript. Here's the code I'm using so far as per Adobe's site:

```
addChild(new Bitmap(new myBitmap(100, 100)));
```

and this works, but changing the dimensions in those brackets doesn't. How can I change the dimensions?

Also, how can I change the position of the bitmap? Right now it's at 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

You first get a handler of that bitmap:

```
var theBitmap:Bitmap=new myBitmap();
```

Then, you can change its coordinates:

```
theBitmap.x=100;
theBitmap.y=100;
addChild(theBitmap);
```

In order to do scaling, you can also alter its `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties as with any other displayed object. In order to make a Bitmap object to be of certain size on screen, you have to scale it so that scaling parameter equals (new dimensions)/(old dimensions). But, if you want something else, you have to explain it further.